# How to make the same baseline for buttons with same size

Tags: android, xml

[As you can see the third button is below other, I want them to be in the same baseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME166.png)

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorDayButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/send_btn"
    android:text="@string/send"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/statistics_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorDayButton"
    android:text="@string/statistics"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startAgain_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorDayButton"
    android:text="@string/start_again"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText" />
```

So, what should I do? Help me out, please

Comment: add your full xml code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Add the property `android:maxLines="1"` for your button. It will wrap your text to a single line

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/startAgain_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorDayButton"
    android:text="@string/start_again"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText" />
```